# what is the probability of $\mathbb{P}(Y=r)$ where $Y$ is the number of the colored coin

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory

For the i.i.d Bernoulli processes $X_{i}, i=1,...,n$, which is $$\mathbb{P}(X_{i}=1)=1$$ ($X_{i}=1$ means the coin is head and $X_{i}=0$ is tail).
Now adding another i.i.d Bernoulli processes $Y_i=1$ on $X_{i}$ if the headed coin is colored with probability $p'$ and  $Y_i=0$ if the headed coin is not colored with probability $1-p'$. (i.e., given the tossing of the coin, and then color coins which are headed)

> My question is that what is the probability of $\mathbb{P}(Y=r)$ where $Y=\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i$ is the number of the colored coin?

I know the answer is $Y$ is Bernoulli$(n, pp')$. But how to prove? I feel the computation is complicated.

$\mathbb{P}(Y=r)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(Y=r | X=i)\mathbb{P}(X=i)$
, where $X=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$.
I can get
$$\mathbb{P}(Y=r)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\binom{i}{r}(p')^r(q')^{i-r}\binom{n}{i}p^iq^{n-r},$$
where $q=1-p, q'=1-p'.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you believe that $Y_1, \ldots, Y_n$ is a sequence of independent Bernoulli random variables with probability of success $pp'$, then *by definition* $\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i$ is a binomial random variable with number of trials $n$ and success probability $pp'$.

Comment: But why $Y_{i}$ with probability $pp'$?

Comment: In other words, how can you know the tossing and coloring are independent?

Comment: @LoveQYG $P(Y_i=1)  = P(Y_i = 1 \mid X_i = 1) P(X_i = 1) + P(Y_i = 1 \mid X_i = 0) P(X_i = 0) = p' \cdot p + 0 \cdot (1-p)$.